# Background of a ToggleButton sticking out over its border

Tags: java, css, javafx, togglebutton

The background of a `ToggleButton` sticking out over its bottom border.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

[image: screenshot]

I set up id for `ToggleButton` in SceneBuilder.

*CSS:*

```
#blue-unselected {
    -fx-border-color: #26b4d5;
    -fx-border-radius: 4;
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-radius: 4;
    -fx-font-size:14;
    -fx-text-fill: #26b4d5;
    -fx-font-family: "Verdana Pro Cond SemiBold"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide also you html code, please.

Comment: @maximelian1986 haha it is javafx buddy !css is also used outside html era.

Comment: @pb4now are you using scene builder? If yes you can add effect like dropshadow to button and white line under button will be gone..I did it few days ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add the following attribute:

```
-fx-background-insets: 0;
```

The default attribute value (in [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css)) for `.toggle-button` is defined as:

```
-fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
```

From this value the first part (`0 0 -1 0`) is interesting for you, as you define a single background color. This color will have a `-1` bottom inset (the four values are [top, right, bottom, left]), which results in the 1 pixel sticking-out on the bottom side.

Comment: DVarga -thank you alot Sir - and thank you for the explanation as well (y) :)